# Merge two dataframes based on an exact match in one column and match within an error in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
df1:

A  time B  C
a1 t1   b1 c1 
a2 t2   b2 c2
a3 t3   b3 c3
```

and another dataframe

```
df2:

A  time D E 
a1 t4   d1 e1
a2 t5   d2 e2
a3 t6   d3 e3
```

Assume `time` is in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` e.g. `2019-08-16 15:06:38`

and lets assume:

```
t4 - t1 = 40 seconds
t5 - t2 = -5 seconds
t6 - t3 = 120 seconds
```

I would like to merge these dataframes based on exact match on `A` and a match on column `time` with some acceptable difference between the dataframes , for example with in 1 min.

So my output would look like:

```
df3 :

A  B  C  D  E time(from df1)
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 t1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 t2
```

See that `a3` is not there because even though it matches on column `A` the difference in time exceeded the acceptable limit.

How can I do this? If not for the "acceptable difference" part I would do like:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("A", "time"))
```

Comment: @akrun Is it not possible to view the string as a date with `as.Date()` while comparing? I may be missing something.

Comment: Yes, if it is the date format i.e. '2013-05-10'

Comment: Yes it is in time format. I can edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar joins using `sqldf` or `foverlaps` from `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Or a non-equi inner join from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("start", "end") := .(time-60*60, time+60*60)]
df2[df1, on=.(A, time>=start, time<=end), nomatch=0L, .(A, B, C, D, E, time=i.time)]
```